# \includestandalone does not create a pdf

Tags: standalone

Somehow `\includestandalone` from the `standalone` package does not create a pdf with this main file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}  
\begin{figure}[h]
\includestandalone[mode=buildnew]{test2}
\includestandalone[mode=image]{test2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This is a code of the standalone file:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw[->] (0,1cm)--++(14,-5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I thought from reading the manual of the [standalone](http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/standalone/standalone.pdf) package usage of (with pdflatex):

```
\includestandalone[mode=buildnew]{test2}
```

will give me in my folder a pdf file `test2.pdf` after compilation, but I do not have it, that is why the second line of my code:

```
\includestandalone[mode=image]{test2}
```

does not work, no pdf - no compilation it says:)

Please explain why it could be so that I do not get pdf after compilation.

Comment: Works fine here. You need to compile with `shell-escape` enabled, have you done that?

Comment: `\includestandalone[mode=buildnew]{test2}
\includestandalone[mode=image]{test2}` does not work, cause the first line creates pdf with name 'test2.pdf' (`'` - is a symbol which surrounds file name). So compiler can not find test2.pdf. How it could be solved?

Comment: Really? That does not happen here (Kubuntu 13.10, v1.1b of `standalone`) , I get `test2.pdf`.  Add `\listfiles` before `\documentclass` to get a list of packages and their versions near the end of the log file.

Comment: There is something similar, but I can make it work:http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85055/latex-standalone-always-rebuilds-apostroph-in-filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer to my question. It was not easy to find.
[Latex Standalone always rebuilds / apostroph in filename?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85055/latex-standalone-always-rebuilds-apostroph-in-filename)

`Standalone` package should be updated with this (if you use MiKTEX):https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/standalone/downloads. Then it works perfectly.