# standalone does not create a pdf (build new option)

Tags: standalone

i'm using the `standalone` package within my main file and i want to input a lot of tikz pictures generated with `matlab2tikz`. Within the documentation of [standalone](http://mirror.physik-pool.tu-berlin.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/standalone/standalone.pdf) i read that the `build new` option creates a pdf of the figure which can be used for faster compilations after the first compilation. So i equipped my example file with the necessary options - but there is no pdf generated for the figure that is included in the main file.

So, i found a similar post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162492/includestandalone-does-not-create-a-pdf) but i didn't find a solution for me - and i'm not allowed to comment...

So this is my main.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[mode=buildnew]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/use comma}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{tikz}
%
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includestandalone[width=0.8\linewidth]{fig_01}
\caption{mycaption}
\label{fig:01}
\end{figure}
%
\end{document}
```

While this in the content of the fig_01.tex:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{grffile}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (2,2) ellipse (3cm and 1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Using this produces a pdf for the whole document including the figure itself. But there is no extra pdf generated for the file fig_01.tex. So can you help me to get this done and fastening the compilation process?

I'm using "pdflatex" with the option -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode.
I already tried to add the option `-shell-escape` and `--shell-escape` for the `pdflatex` command but then i receive the following log: **sh: pdflatex: command not found** and 
**Graphic 'fig_01.pdf' could not be build** while no extra pdf is generated.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer to my question using this [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271221/texmaker-command-not-found-on-macos-el-capitan). While `pdflatex` including the option `-shell-escape` couldn't be found during former compilations, everything works fine now. Changing the folder for the commands to **/Library/TeX/texbin/...** and adding the same into the **Build->Commands ($PATH)** in the settings did what i was looking for.