# How to replace photo in moderncv classic with a QR code?

Tags: graphics, moderncv, includegraphics, qrcode

I am making my resume using the `moderncv` package with the `classic` style.

I wish to replace the photo with a QR-code to my personal website, using the `qrcode` package.

I tried replacing the argument of the `\photo` command with the corresponding `\qrcode{...}` command, but this fails with a LaTeX error message:

```
\photo[64pt][0.5pt]{\qrcode[hyperlink,height=64pt]{http://www.ctan.org}}
```

Here is a `MWE` that illustrates the idea I am trying:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{qrcode}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\address{83 Fancy Avenue}{Noweheresville}{Gotham City 24061} 
\phone[mobile]{123 456 7890}
\email{someone@xyz.com}

% \photo[64pt][0.5pt]{example-image-a}  % works fine
\photo[64pt][0.5pt]{\qrcode[hyperlink,height=64pt]{http://www.ctan.org}} % produces an error

\begin{document}
   \makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

How can I achieve the desired goal?

#### Update

I now understand that `\photo` is essentialy a wrapper for `includegraphics`, and therefore expects a file path and/or file name as its argument.

- Is it possible to re-define `\photo` to be flexible enough to accept either a `latex` command or a graphics file path and/or file name?
- Failing that, at least is it possible to automate the inclusion of a QR-code image that automatically updates whenever the URL argument to the `\qrcode` command is updated i.e. avoid compilation of multiple documents?

Comment: Are you loading the `qrcode` package? I don't think moderncv loads it, or at least it didn't last time I checked, which was a few years ago

Comment: @ChrisH yes, my `MWE` forgot to include it. Updated the `mwe` suitably. The errror is not due to this.

Comment: It seems that the argument of `\photo` is a graphics file, not a LaTeX command. Have you tried to compile the qrcode to a pdf file, and to include the latter?

Comment: @marmot that doesn't sound like an elegant option to me. Is it possible to redefine `\photo` to accept both LaTeX commands as well as as image file paths?

Comment: @marmot If I want to update the `qr code` in the future, I have to remember to re-compile the qr code image. That's tedious and error-prone. At the very least can we have one single compilation that automatically updates the image whenever the `qrcode` command arguments are updated?

Comment: You can do `grep photo /usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/` to see how the photo is used. It will require a substantial surgery to redefine the command, but it is certainly not impossible. The question is whether or not you want to do this major surgery. It *would* have been probably more elegant if the definition read `\NewDocumentCommand{\photo}{O{64pt}O{0.4pt}m}{\def\@photowidth{#1}\def\@photoframewidth{#2}\def\@photo{\includegraphics{#3}}}` and then all `\includegraphics` would have been stripped off from where `\@photo` is used.

Comment: I am certainly not more expert than Ignasi, who will certainly be able to do as you suggest, or to use just standalone for that.

Comment: @marmot Not to take credit away from them, but the solution below involves compiling two different documents, which is not a good idea. Can you please elaborate on the use of `standalone` for this purpose?

Comment: You could use it like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/301617/121799) but really, what's wrong with Ignasi's solution? Or use `externalize`. Or hack the `\photo` command, which I personally wouldn't do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code of class `moderncv`, style `classic` you can find an if-then-else construct checking if a `\photo` is defined (printing it) or not (doing nothing).  I added inside the empty case a new if-then-else testing, if a new command `\qrphoto` is defined. If it is defined the code prints it, in the other case it does nothing.

The new command for the `\qrphoto` is:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\qrphoto}{O{64pt}O{0.4pt}m}{\def\@qrphotowidth{#1}\def\@qrphotoframewidth{#2}\def\@qrphoto{#3}}
```

With this command I define the needed values `\@qrphotowidth` etc. for later usage.

Now we can patch the original command with

```
\patchcmd{\makecvhead}%
  {%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}{}%
  }% code to patch
  {% new code <=========================================================
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
      {%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@qrphoto}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \if@left%
            \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}\fi%
          \color{black}% <======================== to get a black qrcode
          \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@qrphotoframewidth}%
          \ifdim\@qrphotoframewidth=0pt%
            \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
          \raisebox{1cm}{\framebox{\qrcode[hyperlink,height=\@qrphotowidth]{\@qrphoto}}} 
        }
      }%
  }% end new code <=====================================================
  {}% success
  {\fail}% failure
```

The command `\raisebox[1cm]` is needed to get the qr-code on the right position (I did not search for the reason, why I need it here. The used value is okay for sizes of the resulting qr-code of 2cm (I used for the example code) or more. If your qr-code should be smaller you need to change my used value of `1cm` to a lower value. You will have to try it out.

As you can see I deleted the command `\includegraphics`. With command `\qrphoto` \qrcode... from package `qrcode`.

With the command

```
\qrphoto[2cm][0.5pt]{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474546/}
```

for example you can add an qr-code-image with a hight and width of `2cm`, a frame around it with a line of `0.5pt` and the content of the qr-code-image is `https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474546/` (this question).

So with the following complete MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{qrcode}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\address{83 Fancy Avenue}{Noweheresville}{Gotham City 24061} 
\phone[mobile]{123 456 7890}
\email{someone@xyz.com}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\qrphoto}{O{64pt}O{0.4pt}m}{\def\@qrphotowidth{#1}\def\@qrphotoframewidth{#2}\def\@qrphoto{#3}}
% to patch the code of moderncv, version 2.0.0
%\usepackage{etoolbox} % already loaded in moderncv <===================
\patchcmd{\makecvhead}%
  {%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}{}%
  }% code to patch
  {% new code <=========================================================
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
      {%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@qrphoto}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \if@left%
            \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}\fi%
          \color{black}% <======================== to get a black qrcode
          \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@qrphotoframewidth}%
          \ifdim\@qrphotoframewidth=0pt%
            \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
          \raisebox{1cm}{\framebox{\qrcode[hyperlink,height=\@qrphotowidth]{\@qrphoto}}} 
        }
      }%
  }% end new code <=====================================================
  {}% success
  {\fail}% failure
\makeatother

%\photo[64pt][0.5pt]{example-image}
\qrphoto[2cm][0.5pt]{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474546/} % 


\begin{document}
  \makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

you get the following result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Please note that you can only print a photo or a qr-code. If you have a defined `\photo` and `\qrphoto` only the photo is printed!

Comment: this produces a coloured QR code when the CV colour is set eg. `\moderncvcolor{blue}` produces a QR code with blue dots instead of black

Comment: I will accept the answer for now since it works brilliantly. Whenever you have a chance, please edit the answer by changing the argument  of `\color` from `color1` to `black`

Comment: It is officially recommended that there must be an extra margin/white-space padding around any QR code. I wish to get rid of the `fbox` around it by setting `\qrphoto[2cm][0pt]`, but in this case, the base of the QR code does not align with the base of the email address, but is rather lifted upwards. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Manually raising/lowering does not seem like a robust action. If the `personal information` section changes in the future, clearly the base will have to be re-aligned. Can't be always align both to the bottom, something like a `varwidth` or `minipage` or `subfig` which specify the `[b]` alignment argument?

Comment: The answer below by lgnasi does not seem to have any alignment issues. When I tried that, it automatically aligned the QR code with the base of personal info. Can you maybe take a look and see why this might be the case?

Comment: no worries, This is already very nice. Thanks a lot for your help on this.

Answer (score 7):

`\photo` command wants a file suitable to be included with an `\includegraphics` command. Therefore, I think the easiest solution would be to create your own qrcode within an `standalone` document and use the result as photo in moderncv.

```
%File qrcode.tex -> qrcode.pdf
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\begin{document}
\qrcode[hyperlink,height=64pt]{http://www.ctan.org}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\address{83 Fancy Avenue}{Noweheresville}{Gotham City 24061} 
\phone[mobile]{123 456 7890}
\email{someone@xyz.com}

\photo[64pt][0.5pt]{qrcode}

\begin{document}
   \makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Update: All in one ;-)

With `filecontents` package and an `\immediate` command it's possible to join both files into one and compile both together:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{myqrcode.tex} %<- This is the qrcode file name
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\begin{document}
\qrcode[hyperlink,height=64pt]{http://www.ctan.org}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\immediate\write18{pdflatex myqrcode.tex}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\address{83 Fancy Avenue}{Noweheresville}{Gotham City 24061} 
\phone[mobile]{123 456 7890}
\email{someone@xyz.com}

\photo[64pt][0.5pt]{myqrcode} %<- Insert previous name

\begin{document}
   \makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: @lgnasi thank you. But this does not look like a nice option.Is it possible to redefine `\photo` to accept both LaTeX commands as well as as image file paths? If I want to update the `qr code` in the future, I have to remember to compile the original image. That's tedious and error-prone. At the very least can we have one single compilation that automatically updates the image whenever the `qrcode` command arguments are updated?

Comment: @Krishna You can do it with `filecontents` help. See my updated answer.

Comment: @lgnasi Yes, just finished trying your combined solution with the `filecontents` package. It works! Thank you. Upvoted and marked as accepted.