No color in moderncv
A few months ago my moderncv yielded colors as I defined them, but when I tried it recently, there is no color (only black an gray). How can I fix it so that the color is shown?
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.26,0.7,0.68}
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0.25,0.28,0.3}

\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[top=1.0cm, bottom=1.0cm, left=1.4cm, right=1.4cm]{geometry}

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\qrphoto}{O{64pt}O{0.4pt}m}{\def\@qrphotowidth{#1}\def\@qrphotoframewidth{#2}\def\@qrphoto{#3}}
% to patch the code of moderncv, version 2.0.0
%\usepackage{etoolbox} % already loaded in moderncv <===================
\patchcmd{\makecvhead}%
{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}{}%
}% code to patch
{% new code <=========================================================
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@qrphoto}}%
        {}%
        {%
            \if@left%
            \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}\fi%
            \color{black}% <======================== to get a black qrcode
            \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@qrphotoframewidth}%
            \ifdim\@qrphotoframewidth=0pt%
            \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
            \raisebox{1.5cm}{\framebox{\qrcode[hyperlink,height=\@qrphotowidth]{\@qrphoto}}} 
        }
    }%
}% end new code <=====================================================
{}% success
{\fail}% failure
\makeatother

%\photo[64pt][0.5pt]{example-image}

\qrphoto[3cm][0.5pt]{https://google.com} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474546/


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 

\firstname{first name}
\familyname{last name}
\title{first line of header \\ second line}
\email{yannickpoule@gmail.com}                      

\address{my street}{my city} 
\social[linkedin][www.google.com]{my name}
\extrainfo{Permis B}
\extrainfo{info\\info\\info}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \vspace*{\baselineskip}
    \setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.4cm}
    
    
    \section{\textbf{Compétences}}
    \cvitem{}{\textbf{info} -complement}
    \cvitem{}{\textbf{info}}
    \cvitem{}{\textbf{info} - complement}
    \cvitem{}{\textbf{info} - complement}
    \cvitem{}{\textbf{info} - Virtualbox}
    \cvitem{}{\textbf{info} - complement}
    
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    
    \section{\textbf{Formations}}
    \cventry{2021-2022}{ grade}{organisation}{city}{}{}
    \cventry{2020}{grade}{organisation}{}{}{}
    \cventry{2013}{grade}{organisation}{city}{}{}
    
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    
    \section{\textbf{Expériences professionnelles}}
    \cventry{08/2023 -- 09/2023}{info}{organisation}{city}{}{}
    \cventry{09/2020 -- 03/2021}{info}{organisation}{city}{}{}
    \cventry{09/2019 -- 06/2020}{info}{organisation}{city}{}{}
    \cventry{09/2019 -- 06/2020}{info}{organisation}{city}{}{}
    \cventry{09/2019 -- 06/2020}{info}{organisation}{city}{}{}
    \cventry{08/2014 -- 09/2015}{info}{organisation}{city}{}{}
    \cventry{08/2013}{info}{organisation}{city}{service international}{}    
    \cventry{07/2011}{info}{organisation}{city}{}{}
    
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        
        \section{\textbf{Centres d'intérêt}}
        \cvitem{}{\textbf{Randonnée pédestre}}
        \cvitem{}{\textbf{Cuisine}}
        \cvitem{}{\textbf{Jeux vidéo}}
        
        
        \section{\textbf{Langues parlées}}
        \cvitem{\textbf{Anglais}}{Lu, parlé, écrit}
        \cvitem{}{}
        \cvitem{}{}
        
    \end{multicols}
    
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    
    
    
\end{document}


Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Indeed I can't reproduce the issue on Overleaf, which uses TeX Live from a few months ago. Which compiler and which version do you use?

I install miktek (is at the last update) an texstudio 4.8.4, and it work perfectly fine 2 month ago.

@poulikof please note that texstudio 4.8.4 is not a compiler but an editor. A compiler in this case would be one of the engines pdfTeX, LuaTeX, XeTeX.

@Skillmon Oh, I didn't understand, sorry. In fact I didn't modify the automatic setting, and I don't know which one is used. But now I try with pdfTeX, LuaTeX, XeLaTeX and LaTeX and the result is the same.

@poulikof nothing to apologise for, terminology can be confusing for beginners and we were all at that place somewhen.

Define the theme colors before \moderncvstyle.

% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

%% Base colors here <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0,0,0} % main text color
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.26,0.7,0.68}% main theme color
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0.25,0.28,0.3}
\moderncvstyle{classic} 

\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[top=1.0cm, bottom=1.0cm, left=1.4cm, right=1.4cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\qrphoto}{O{64pt}O{0.4pt}m}{\def\@qrphotowidth{#1}\def\@qrphotoframewidth{#2}\def\@qrphoto{#3}}
% to patch the code of moderncv, version 2.0.0
%\usepackage{etoolbox} % already loaded in moderncv <===================
\patchcmd{\makecvhead}%
{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}{}%
}% code to patch
{% new code <=========================================================
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@qrphoto}}%
        {}%
        {%
            \if@left%
            \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}\fi%
            \color{black}% <======================== to get a black qrcode
            \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@qrphotoframewidth}%
            \ifdim\@qrphotoframewidth=0pt%
            \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
            \raisebox{1.5cm}{\framebox{\qrcode[hyperlink,height=\@qrphotowidth]{\@qrphoto}}} 
        }
    }%
}% end new code <=====================================================
{}% success
{\fail}% failure
\makeatother

%\photo[64pt][0.5pt]{example-image}

\qrphoto[3cm][0.5pt]{https://google.com} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474546/


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\firstname{first name}
\familyname{last name}
\title{first line of header \\ second line}
\email{yannickpoule@gmail.com}                      

\address{my street}{my city} 
\social[linkedin][www.google.com]{my name}
\extrainfo{Permis B}
\extrainfo{info\\info\\info}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \vspace*{\baselineskip}
    \setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.4cm}
    
    
    \section{\textbf{Compétences}}
    \cvitem{}{\textbf{info} -complement}
    \cvitem{}{\textbf{info}}
    \cvitem{}{\textbf{info} - complement}
    \cvitem{}{\textbf{info} - complement}
    \cvitem{}{\textbf{info} - Virtualbox}
    \cvitem{}{\textbf{info} - complement}
    
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    
    \section{\textbf{Formations}}
    \cventry{2021-2022}{ grade}{organisation}{city}{}{}
    \cventry{2020}{grade}{organisation}{}{}{}
    \cventry{2013}{grade}{organisation}{city}{}{}
    
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    
    \section{\textbf{Expériences professionnelles}}
    \cventry{08/2023 -- 09/2023}{info}{organisation}{city}{}{}
    \cventry{09/2020 -- 03/2021}{info}{organisation}{city}{}{}
    \cventry{09/2019 -- 06/2020}{info}{organisation}{city}{}{}
    \cventry{09/2019 -- 06/2020}{info}{organisation}{city}{}{}
    \cventry{09/2019 -- 06/2020}{info}{organisation}{city}{}{}
    \cventry{08/2014 -- 09/2015}{info}{organisation}{city}{}{}
    \cventry{08/2013}{info}{organisation}{city}{service international}{}    
    \cventry{07/2011}{info}{organisation}{city}{}{}
    
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        
        \section{\textbf{Centres d'intérêt}}
        \cvitem{}{\textbf{Randonnée pédestre}}
        \cvitem{}{\textbf{Cuisine}}
        \cvitem{}{\textbf{Jeux vidéo}}
        
        
        \section{\textbf{Langues parlées}}
        \cvitem{\textbf{Anglais}}{Lu, parlé, écrit}
        \cvitem{}{}
        \cvitem{}{}
        
    \end{multicols}
    
    \vspace{0.5cm}  
    
\end{document}

Define the col


That work perfectly fine, thank to you.

The moderncv class
(moderncv.cls) defines a number of basic colours in the following way:
% colors
%-------
\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0,0,0}% main default color, normally left to black
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0,0,0}% primary scheme color
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0,0,0}% secondary scheme color
\definecolor{color3}{rgb}{0,0,0}% tertiary scheme color

While these are all (the same) black, it brings them into existence. This way themes/styles can use these colours, or whichever new assignment they are given by the end user. See, for example, the colour settings within the classic style (set with \moderncvstyle{classic}; taken from moderncvstyleclassic.sty):
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%               Colors
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% head and footer
\colorlet{lastnamecolor}{color2}
\colorlet{namecolor}{lastnamecolor}
\colorlet{headrulecolor}{lastnamecolor!50}
\colorlet{firstnamecolor}{lastnamecolor!50}
\colorlet{titlecolor}{color2}
\colorlet{addresscolor}{color2}
\colorlet{quotecolor}{color1}
\colorlet{pictureframecolor}{color1}
% body
\colorlet{bodyrulecolor}{color1}
\colorlet{sectioncolor}{color1}
\colorlet{subsectioncolor}{color1}
\colorlet{hintstylecolor}{color0}
% letter
\colorlet{letterclosingcolor}{color2}
% skillmatrix
\colorlet{skillmatrixfullcolor}{color1}
\colorlet{skillmatrixemptycolor}{color2!30}

So, with a call to set the style, whatever was defined for color0, color1, color2 (and color3) will be used to define the other elements of the document. Therefore, updating these colours after setting the style will have no effect. This is why you need to update/redefine your colours prior to a call that sets the style:
% Update/redefine base colours
\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.26,0.7,0.68}
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0.25,0.28,0.3}

% Set the moderncv style to classic
\moderncvstyle{classic} 


This required change was initiated with moderncv 2.4.0 (Jul 8, 2024). From the change log (emphasis mine):

version 2.4.0 (08 Jul 2024)

Rewrote user guide, thanks to David Seus (#58, #106, #169).
Fixed "Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)" warning in \makecvtitle (#162).
Fixed unnecessary academicons warning when academicons aren't used (#161).
Fixed page counts unnecessarily linking to the last page of the PDF (#159).
Added support for an optional signature in the cover letter (#157).
Added support for non-ASCII characters in links (#155).
Added option to force a homepage link to use HTTP rather than HTTPS (#154).
Passed unicode option directly to hyperref to avoid conflicts with the
inclusion of hyperref by other packages (#148).
Fixed the sender block on the cover letter in banking style (#146).
Added option to classic style to align header elements at the top (#144).
Added Twitch, YouTube, TikTok, Instagram, SoundCloud, Steam, Xbox, PlayStation
and Battle.net social icons (#131).
Removed extra dash in PDF metadata when CV title is empty (#116).
Added support for an optional subject line in the cover letter (#114).
Added Discord social icon (#112).
Replace instances of ~~~ in codebase with \hspace to be more compatible with
babel for Spanish (#109).
Added Codeberg and Mastodon social icons (#107).
New \social options: arXiv, INSPIRE (#185)
Systematize colors and make them user adjustable. See documentation for details.
This requires the \moderncvcolor to be issued BEFORE \moderncvstyle (#151).
all styles: make the head options details and nodetails available to the user. (previously they were hidden). Oldstyle does not respond too well to nodetails (#150).
casual style: make the head options alternate, details and nodetails available to the user. (previously they were hidden) (#150).
Setting \listitemsymbolspace allows custom spacing between list symbol and text item (for \cvlistitem and \cvlistdoubleitem) (#74).
Introducing \cvtripleitem command for items in three columns. Closing feature request #174.
Fixed wrong \cvlistitem \vspace caused by multiline section titles in fancy style (#69).



It's explained why it's work a few months ago. Thank for the explanations.
